# How to add a second condition in a rails Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to do something like SQL `AND` to add a second condition to this:

```
Article
  .where("date_trunc('day', created_at) = ?", Date.yesterday-(params[:increment].to_i))
  .order('articles.created_at DESC')
```

The second condition is if the `'site_id' attribute = "HIDE"`.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `where` clause with the required condition:

```
Article
  .where("date_trunc('day', created_at) = ?", Date.yesterday-(params[:increment].to_i))
  .where(site_id: 'HIDE')
  .order('articles.created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AND` inside your `where` statement:

```
Article
  .where("date_trunc('day', created_at) = ? AND site_id = 'HIDE'", Date.yesterday-(params[:increment].to_i))
  .order("articles.created_at DESC")
```